# Too much spacing on <td> - TABLE

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have some issues with my tables. It seems that the distance between the field name and text boxes are a bit big.

Are there any issues that I am making which causing this? How can I reduce the spaces? Check out the image below.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Here's my HTML:

```
<h5>Free Room of Cleaning & Carpet Audit</h5>

<table border="0" border-collapse:collapse; width:80% colspan="3">
<tbody>

<tr>
<td>Name: <span style="color:red;"><strong>*</strong></span></td>
<td>[text* client-name] </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Phone: <span style="color:red;"><strong>*</strong></span></td>
<td> [text* phone] </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Email: <span style="color:red;"><strong>*</strong></span></td>
<td>[email* email]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Best time to call: &nbsp; </td>
<td>[select best-time "Morning" "Afternoon" "After 5pm"] </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td> [text address]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>City</td>
<td>[text city]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>State: </td>
<td>[text state]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Zip:</td>
<td>[text zip]</td>
</tr>

<tr><td colspan="2">Questions/Comments
[textarea questions id:questions] 
</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="2">[submit "Submit"]</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/sLv3e8f5/

Comment: For a start, question the use of table here. Tables should only be used for displaying tabular data. In general a form is not tabular data. You should also be using `<label>` tags.

Comment: The nest question is how do you want them to display?  It sounds like you want the fields not aligned? Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/vhLfd2y2/1/

Answer (score 1):

The way the browser lays out tables by default, each column is sized to try to fit the width of its largest child element. In this case the largest child element is the table cell with the value "best time to call", which is causing the column to expand in width to accommodate that length.

You can give the first column of your table a fixed width to fix this, which will cause your longest line, "best time to call", to wrap.

In the following example I added an `id` to the table, then I targeted the first column of the table using CSS and gave it a `width`. I also gave your "Questions/Comments" form a width so it matches up.

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot result]

---

**Live Demo:**

```css
#thetable td:first-child {
    width: 70px;
}

#qa {
    width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<h5>Free Room of Cleaning & Carpet Audit</h5>

<table id="thetable" border="0" border-collapse:collapse; width:80% colspan="3" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
<tbody>

<tr>
<td>Name: <span style="color:red;"><strong>*</strong></span></td>
<td> <input type="text"> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Phone: <span style="color:red;"><strong>*</strong></span></td>
<td> <input type="text"> </td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Email: <span style="color:red;"><strong>*</strong></span></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Best time to call: &nbsp; </td>
<td><select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Address:</td>
<td> <input type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>City</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>State: </td>
<td>[text state]</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Zip:</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>

<tr><td colspan="2">Questions/Comments
<textarea id="qa" rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
</td></tr>

<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/sLv3e8f5/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `cellspacing="0"`and `cellpadding="0"` on your table,

Comment: The `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` attributes are marked as obsolete in HTML5 (@see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#attr-table-cellpadding).

Comment: I don't find w3schools standards a reliable source to be complaint with, but your point is appreciated. Even in the link you've sent me, the contents are so horribly aligned and placed rigidly on the page, that I would never go around reading it....

Answer (score 0):

Add a

```
margin-left:3px;
```

to the

```
<td>
```

For example,

```
<td style="margin-left:3px;">[text* client-name]</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your spaces are being caused by the "Best time to call" cell. Wrap that cell to two lines to remove the excess spaces.

Comment: @RodelGarcia Maximillian Laumeister's answer is far more complete. I would mark his as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

because table cell is aligned by "Best time to call:  ".
how about use `<ul><li>`

Comment: actually, you use `<td>ab</td>` instead of `<td>a</td><td>b</td>` space will disapear

Answer (score 0):

Getting rid of tables opens you up to a world of possibilities with CSS Styling.

The following is a very quick and dirty example:

```css
label {
    /*float:left;*/
    width: 8em;
    display:block;
    clear:both;   
    margin-top: 10px;
}
input, select {
    float:left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
label.required::after {
    content:'*';
    color: #F00;
    padding-left:0.25em;
}

.required+input, .required+select
{
    background-color:#FCC;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
    <legend>Free Room of Cleaning & Carpet Audit</legend>
    <label class="required" for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    <label class="required" for="phone">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />
    <label class="required" for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
    <label for="call">Best time to call:</label>
    <select id="call" name="call">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <label  for="Address">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Address" name="Address" />
</fieldset>
```